# postgresql 9.6.4: timestamp range query on large table takes forever

Tags: database, postgresql, database-performance

I need some help in analyzing the bad performance of a query executed on a large table containing 83.660.142 million rows which takes up to 25 minutes to more than one hour, depending on the system load, for computation.

I've created the following table that consists of a composite key and 3 indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ds1records(
 userid INT DEFAULT 0,
 clientid VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
 ts TIMESTAMP,
 site VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
 code VARCHAR(400) DEFAULT '');

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS primary_idx ON records (userid, clientid, ts, site, code);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS userid_idx ON records (userid);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ts_idx ON records (ts);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS userid_ts_idx ON records (userid ASC,ts DESC);
```

In a spring batch application I'm executing a query that looks as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM records 
 WHERE userid = ANY(VALUES (2), ..., (96158 more userids) ) 
  AND ( ts < '2017-09-02' AND ts >= '2017-09-01' 
        OR ts < '2017-08-26' AND ts >= '2017-08-25' 
        OR ts < '2017-08-19' AND ts >= '2017-08-18' 
        OR ts < '2017-08-12' AND ts >= '2017-08-11')
```

The User ID's are determined at runtime (number of id's lie between 95.000 and 110.000). For each user I need to extract the page views of the current day and the last same three weekdays. The query always returns rows between 3-4M rows.

Executing the query with the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` option returns the following execution plan.

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1483.40..1246386.43 rows=3761735 width=70) (actual time=108.856..1465501.596 rows=3643240 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1442.38..1444.38 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=33.277..201.819 rows=96159 loops=1)
     Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1
     ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..1201.99 rows=96159 width=4) (actual time=0.006..11.599 rows=96159 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on records  (cost=41.02..6224.01 rows=70 width=70) (actual time=8.865..15.218 rows=38 loops=96159)
     Recheck Cond: (userid = "*VALUES*".column1)
     Filter: (((ts < '2017-09-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ts >= '2017-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((ts < '2017-08-26 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ts >= '2017-08-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((ts < '2017-08-19 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ts >= '2017-08-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR ((ts < '2017-08-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (ts >= '2017-08-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 792
     Heap Blocks: exact=77251145
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on userid_ts_idx  (cost=0.00..41.00 rows=1660 width=0) (actual time=6.593..6.593 rows=830 loops=96159)
           Index Cond: (userid = "*VALUES*".column1)
```

I've adjusted the values of some Postgres tuning parameters (unfortunately with no success):

- effective_cache_size=15GB (probably useless as query is executed just once)
- shared_buffers=15GB
- work_mem=3GB

The application runs computationally expensive tasks (e.g. data fusion/data injection) and consumes roughly 100GB memory, so the system hardware is sufficiently dimensioned with 125GB RAM and 16 cores (OS: Debian).

I'm wondering why postgres is not using the combined index `userid_ts_idx` in its execution plan? Since the timestamp column in the index is sorted in reverse order I would expect postgres to use this to find matching tuples for the range part of the query as it could sequentially go through the index until the condition `ts < '2017-09-02 00:00:00` holds true and return all values until condition `ts >= 2017-09-01 00:00:00` is met. Instead postgres uses the expensive *Bitmap Heap Scan* which does a linear table scan if I understood correctly. Did I misconfigure the db settings or do I have a conceptual misunderstanding?

**Update**

The CTE as suggested in the comments unfortunately did **not** bring any improvements. The Bitmap Heap Scan has been replaced by a Sequantial Scan but the performance is still poor. Following is the updated execution plan:

```
Merge Join  (cost=20564929.37..20575876.60 rows=685277 width=106) (actual time=2218133.229..2222280.192 rows=3907472 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (ids.id = r.userid)
  Buffers: shared hit=2408684 read=181785
  CTE ids
    ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..1289.70 rows=103176 width=4) (actual time=0.002..28.670 rows=103176 loops=1)
  CTE ts
    ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*_1"  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.004 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=10655.37..10913.31 rows=103176 width=4) (actual time=68.476..83.312 rows=103176 loops=1)
    Sort Key: ids.id
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 7909kB
    ->  CTE Scan on ids  (cost=0.00..2063.52 rows=103176 width=4) (actual time=0.007..47.868 rows=103176 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=20552984.25..20554773.54 rows=715717 width=102) (actual time=2218059.941..2221230.585 rows=8085760 loops=1)
    Sort Key: r.userid
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1410084kB
    Buffers: shared hit=2408684 read=181785
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..20483384.24 rows=715717 width=102) (actual time=885849.043..2214665.723 rows=8085767 loops=1)
          Join Filter: (ts.r @> r.ts)
          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 707630821
          Buffers: shared hit=2408684 read=181785
          ->  Seq Scan on records r  (cost=0.00..4379760.52 rows=178929152 width=70) (actual time=0.024..645616.135 rows=178929147 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=2408684 read=181785
          ->  CTE Scan on ts  (cost=0.00..0.08 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=4 loops=178929147)
Planning time: 126.110 ms
Execution time: 2222514.566 ms
```

Comment: Any chance it is constrained by disk reads? Please use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) ` next time. This will give you some insight into buffering. As we see, the heap scan consumes most of time.  https://explain.depesz.com/s/wJBk

Comment: Thanks for the hint... According to *iotop* the disk reads are fluctuating between 1 and 7 M/s but I've also seen some peaks at 17M/s. What should be the average for a good performance?

Comment: With several ORs in that set of date ranges I don't think it will `hold true` the latest date proceeding backward to earliest given date. The Filter indicates it deals with each range `(... or ...) and (... or ...) and (... or ...) and (... or ...)`

Comment: A couple of quick points. Do you really mean 83.660.142 million  rows? As in 83x10^12 rows? Or just 83M rows? Big difference. Second if your return set is large and gets any kind of sorting etc, it will spill to disk. The default is to spill to the same disk that your data is stored on. Moving the temp tablespace elsewhere can make a big difference here, as can larger work_mem (to an extent)

Comment: @Used_By_Already Then any ideas on how to optimise the query in order to enforce this?

Comment: @Scott Marlowe I actually meant 83M rows. I've used the german thousands separator, sorry for that :) Shouldn't the query optimizer display sortings in the execution plan?

Comment: Any chance in making that `ANY(VALUES (2), ..., (96158 more userids) ) ` into a subquery? Also without the correct parenthesis on that TS filter those AND operator does absolutely nothing... it should be `AND ( (ts<... and ts>=...) OR (ts<... and ts>=...).... ) `

Comment: You could try `userid = any (array[2,3,4,.....])` instead of the `values` clause.

Comment: Another option to try would be to move the `values()` clause into a CTE and then join against that: e.g.: `with userids (id) as (values (2), ...) select r.* from records r join userids u on u.id = r.userid ...`

Comment: I was also going to suggest a CTE, for the overall date range subset. I would also suggest you use parentheses in your code on those date ranges `(... or ...) and (... or ...)`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I don't see any benefit of using a subquery !? The query returns the correct results, even by omitting the paranthesis.

Comment: Something like: https://privatebin.net/?e5e2b2955bac91dc#df3qz1IwXPgDZPRxAGtyH5ilZN+n9uMC8+yS9NP+okg=

Comment: The main benefit of a subquery or a join would be the use of indexes (not the the list would not) and the lack of the parenthesis SEEMS like to get you the correct results. Review your data carefully. And this was suggested by two other people. You should take that into consideration.

Comment: [data model] `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS primary_idx ON records(...all the columns ... )` looks like a terrible PK. 1) could {user_id, client_is, ts} be the actural natural PK? 2) could client_id be replaced by an integer key (FK to a client table) ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos The parantheses aren't necessary since the `AND` operator has precedence over the `OR` operator but it's better to use it with respect to readability. On this point I would agree.

Comment: @joop regarding 1) No, this key wouldn't be unique as a user with the same client could access different websites within the same hour 2) Again no, the client id is an alpha-numeric string

Comment: 1) A timestamp has a subsecond resolution, better than an hour. 2) it could/should be a number, refering to a table with the client_id strings. IOW: normalize your database model.

Comment: `ANY(VALUES (2), ..., (96158 more userids) ) ` is a very bad habit. (you can even detect this from the  time it takes to *parse* the query (100ms, normaly is around 1ms) . You should put the list of ids into a (temp) table, maybe add an index to this, and join with that table. It also helps to normalise your data model. A database is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get different plan if you would cast that timestamp to date and filter by value list instead.

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS userid_ts_idx ON records (userid ASC,cast(ts AS date) DESC);

SELECT *
  FROM records
 WHERE userid = ANY(VALUES (2), ..., (96158 more userids) )
  AND cast(ts AS date) IN('2017-09-01','2017-08-25','2017-08-18','2017-08-11');
```

Whether it will perform better depends on your data and date range, since I found in my case that Postgres will keep using that index even if date values cover whole table (so a seq scan would be better).

[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=33d4b33ca6301f534096b5f619d5f4a0)

Comment: Converting the timestamp to date is not an option since the data is based on hour granularity. This query would filter out a large bulk of the result set.

Comment: So you actually do something like that? `ts < '2017-08-12 05:00:00' AND ts >= '2017-08-11 13:00:00'`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the fact that this part `IN('2017-09-01','2017-08-25','2017-08-18','2017-08-11')` filters in ranges. I will test your solution.

Comment: It does only because timestamp is cast to date in that condition, so basically it gets rid of time part and compares only dates.

Comment: Lukasz You are a genius!!! It executed the query in about 11 minutes, yeaa :) And as you said, it' s running an Index Scan now! Thank you very much

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński well done. It's one of the 80% cases which can be resolved by simply adding an index :-) regards/pozdrowienia